What is the result of this bitwise "|" operator: ok|=(s[i]=='0' && s[i+1]=='1')
I don't understand this code line with the bitwise | operator.

ok|=(s[i]=='0' && s[i+1]=='1');

What is the result?
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void solve(){
    string s; //`string`
    cin>>s //`string input`
    int res=1;
    bool ok=false;

    for(int i=0;i+1<(int) (s.size());i++){
        res+=(s[i]!=s[i+1]);
        ok|=(s[i]=='0' && s[i+1]=='1');//`this line i dont understand`
    }
    cout<<res<<'\n';
}

cutting binary operation.

|= is a compound-assignment form of bitwise-OR. a |= b is roughly the same as a  = a | b.

I don't understand it either, ok is never used in a meaningful way after write.

Arguably, this is an abusive operation, since it's bitwise, not logical; but unfortunately there is no logical compound assignment operator :-(

It's not uncommon for people to use the bitwise compound assignment operators in lieu of the absence of boolean compound assignment operators like Kerrek said. It usually ends up working out thanks to int -> bool conversion.

Still, if ok is never used then the result doesn't matter anyway. Since s is just a std::string there are no useful sideeffects either; just ditch the line entirely.

The program iterates every character of a string and compares the current character with the following, ok will be true if anywhere in the string you have the sequence "01" as you accumulate the results (|=) of every comparison (...=='0' && ...=='1'). But as said in other comments, the result is not used at all in this program.

(s[i]=='0' && s[i+1]=='1') is a boolean expression, the result will be true if s[i] is '0' and s[i+1] is '1', otherwise the result will be false.  So, ok will be updated on each loop iteration using either ok|=true or ok|=false.
But, there is no |= operator defined for bool, so the compiler will convert both ok and the true|false result to int first, then perform the bitwise operation using ints, and then assign the result back to ok.
Effectively, the statement:
ok|=(s[i]=='0' && s[i+1]=='1');
Is equivalent to this:
ok = bool(int(ok) | int(s[i]=='0' && s[i+1]=='1'));
As an int, true is 1 and false is 0. Any bit OR'ed with 0 remains the same value, and any bit OR'ed with 1 becomes 1.
So, let's say (s[i]=='0' && s[i+1]=='1') evaluates to true. Then you end up with:
ok = bool(int(ok) | 1);
If ok was false then you have:
ok = bool(int(false) | 1);
   = bool(0 | 1);
   = bool(1);
   = true;

If ok was true then you have:
ok = bool(int(true) | 1);
   = bool(1 | 1);
   = bool(1);
   = true;

Now, let's say (s[i]=='0' && s[i+1]=='1') evaluates to false instead. Then you end up with:
ok = bool(int(ok) | 0);
If ok was false then you have:
ok = bool(int(false) | 0);
   = bool(0 | 0);
   = bool(0);
   = false;

If ok was true then you have:
ok = bool(int(true) | 0);
   = bool(1 | 0);
   = bool(1);
   = true;

So, the moral of the of the story is: ok is initialized to false, and then the loop will toggle ok to true if any iteration detects the substring "01" in s.
